# Increment input name using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I have a div with some radio buttons, and the input names are cty_1. If i add more div the input names inside that divs should become cty_2, cty_3, etc.respectively.

Here's my code:

```
    <div class="category">
        <div class="col-md-6">
           <input type="radio" name="cty_1" id="1" value="car">
           <label for="1">car</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
           <input type="radio" name="cty_1" id="2" value="bike">
           <label for="2">bike</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If another div is added, i want that like

```
<div class="category">
        <div class="col-md-6">
           <input type="radio" name="cty_1" id="1" value="car">
           <label for="1">car</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
           <input type="radio" name="cty_1" id="2" value="bike">
           <label for="2">bike</label>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="category">
        <div class="col-md-6">
           <input type="radio" name="cty_2" id="3" value="phone">
           <label for="3">phone</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
           <input type="radio" name="cty_2" id="4" value="computer">
           <label for="4">computer</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**NB:** i don't know javascript.

Comment: well your ids would also need to change

Comment: Before asking for help here you should go study and try to come up with a solution showing that you've tried instead of just asking for help. http://www.w3schools.com/js/ -> javascript tutorial

Comment: So you need to clone() the parent, select the elements, and change the ids/names.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Do you use jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wkLssnLw/2/)

```
//Html 
<div id="divMain">      
 </div>

//jQuery Code
var valuesArr=["car","bike","truck","Test4","Test5"];
var cityCounter=1;
var idCounter=1;
var addCategoryFlag=false;
function CallHtml(){
    var html="";
    for(var i=0;i<valuesArr.length;i++){    
       if(idCounter%2!=0){
          html+='<div class="category">';          
       }
       else{
          addCategoryFlag=true;
       }
        html+='<div class="col-md-6">';
        html+='   <input type="radio" name="cty_'+cityCounter+'" id="'+idCounter+'" value="'+valuesArr[i]+'">';
        html+='   <label for="'+idCounter+'">'+valuesArr[i]+'</label>';
        html+='</div>';
        if(addCategoryFlag){
                html+='</div>';
          addCategoryFlag=false;
          cityCounter++;
        }
        idCounter++;
    }

    $("#divMain").html(html);
}

CallHtml();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't need the button. If i add the div once more or twice,etc. the name should change automatically to cty_2,cty_3,... I hope you understand.

Comment: You can check it fiddle. When new div added it automatically changed.

Comment: i think, your code is executed only when the button is pressed. If i was wrong, correct me.

Comment: Yes, but how html will add automatically?

Comment: There is some php codes.The values are sql data. i use foreach, so the div will loop.

Comment: ok so whole html of city section created dynamically using php code using loop correct?

Comment: You can check updated answer and fiddle as per your need.

Comment: This is not am looking for. Thanks for your commitment.Maybe you can help me. consider that i have three category divs, each div have 4 radio buttons as shown above. And i don't put any name to that radio buttons.I want its name as cty_1, cty_2, cty_3 using javascript. Not only 3 divs it will vary. Hope you get me. Help me if You can, please....

Comment: The divs must look like i mentioned above in my question

Comment: You can check html of rendered element using browser developer console. It generated same like in question.

Comment: Ok. How can i make 4 options in each div?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery then this is pretty easy. Using the following code, every time you click "Go" a new `category` element will be appended and the `name` and `id` attributes will increment:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <btn class="btn btn-primary">Go</btn>
    <div class="category">
        <div class="col-md-6">
           <input type="radio" name="cty_1" id="1" value="car">
           <label for="1">car</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
           <input type="radio" name="cty_1" id="2" value="bike">
           <label for="2">bike</label>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
$('.btn-primary').on('click',function(){
  var idx = parseInt($('.category').last().index())+1;
  $('.category')
    .last()
    .clone()
    .find('input[type=radio]')
      .each(function(index){
        $(this)
          .attr('name','cty_' + idx)
          .attr('id','cty_' + idx + "_" + index)
          .parent()
            .find('label')
              .attr('for','cty_' + idx + "_" + index)
              .end()
      })
      .end()
    .insertAfter($('.category').last());
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i don't need the button. The new category element is created manually or automatically by queries.It doesn't matter. I only want to change the name, id when new div is added.